# Cannot run Bootstrap and CSS with Node.js, refused to apply style because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bootstrap-5

I was trying to test the Start Bootstrap Bare template using Node.js and Express. ([Link to Start Bootstrap Template](https://startbootstrap.com/template/bare))

I did not modify anything within the HTML, CSS and JavaScript provided with the template. I only made a new index.js used to run Node.js. Here is the index.js code inside the project folder:

```
// using ES6 Modules syntax
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const app = express();
const port = 4000;

// ️ for serving static files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

When trying to run the page in localhost and the port it only displays the HTML, without the CSS and Bootstrap. I inspected the page and opened the console, displaying the following error messages:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4000/css/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
(localhost/:1)
        
GET http://localhost:4000/js/scripts.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) (localhost/:48)

Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:4000/js/scripts.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
(localhost/:1)
```

Is there any way to make this work? It should run the same way I run the HTML, CSS and JavaScript from the template (without the Node.js).

Comment: when you look at the debug network, does styles.css return the desired content?

Answer (score 0):

**Better way for call your css and js like below  code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
<script src="./js/scripts.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Use code as text not as image

Comment: This is correct for basic html but has no relevance to referencing static files served up using express. Please read the question again to better understand.

Answer (score 0):

Change from this

```
 // ️ for serving static files
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));
```

to this

```
// ️ for serving static files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Notice that /public does not have a forward slash at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are using a view engine such as EJS, Handlebars or Pug and you have links to your `styles.css` and `scripts.js` inside the view templates.

However, when you use this:

```js
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));
```

You are setting the root directory for all of your static files to `/public`.

If you have a `/public/css` folder and a `/public/js` folder then inside your html template files you need to reference them relative to that root like this:

```html
<script src="/js/scripts.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
```

Notice the leading `/` before the folder name. That says from the root.

If you are using `./css/styles.css` or even `css/styles.css` then you are telling express the files are relative to the current file, which is not what you want. That's what is causing the errors on the front-end.